# How to validate there is no white space in text field with jQuery

Tags: jquery, regex

Is there any way validating white space in jQuery, I have a field in which I don't want any white space I am using this regexp

```
$('#contact_email').on('input', function() {
                    var input=$(this);
                    var re = /^[a-zA-Z0-9()._-]/;
                    var is_email=re.test(input.val());
                    if(is_email){input.removeClass("invalid").addClass("valid");}
                    else{input.removeClass("valid").addClass("invalid");}
                });
```

Please tell me what am I missing tried every single expression listed here, when I press space no matter how many it remains green valid and when I finish the name and press space it let me write as many spaces as I want ? Is there any way to not allow white space at all ?

Answer (score 0):

You may want something like

```
var re = /^\S+$/;
```

- `\S`  matches anything other tha a space

[**Regex Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/hO9pV1/1)

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest:

```
if ((/\s+/).test(this.value)) {
    $(this).removeClass('valid').addClass('invalid');
}
else {
    $(this).removeClass('invalid').addClass('valid');
}
```

```js
$('#demo').on('input', function() {

  if ((/\s+/).test(this.value)) {
    $(this).removeClass('valid').addClass('invalid');
  } else {
    $(this).removeClass('invalid').addClass('valid');
  }
});
```

```css
.valid {
  border: 2px solid #0f0;
}
.invalid {
  border: 2px solid #f00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="demo" />
```

References:

- JavaScript:

  - [JavaScript Regular Expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).
  - [`RegExp.prototype.test()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test).
- jQuery:

  - [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

Answer (score 0):

hange your regex to:

```
var re = /^[a-zA-Z0-9()._-]+$/;
```

OR

```
var re = /^[\w().-]+$/;
```

You're missing quantifier and anchor `$` to disallow unwanted characters.